# After X restart all XFCE styling is gone (icons,fonts,colors)

Tags: linux, xorg, xfce

I added a monitor with nvidia-settings and after restarting X all my settings seem to have disappeared ..

I tried many things like restoring the xorg.conf - this worked but then I saved to nvidia-settings-rc and then again same problem.

Currently I can't seem to bring back the styling... I even deleted the xorg.conf, deleted the nvidia-settings-rc.. still nothing

Comment: xorg.conf has nothing to do with user-specific window manager (xfce) settings. Are you sure it ever worked? These settings should be stored in your `~/.config/xfce4` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that with Ubuntu 12.10 there's a bug; it has been filed already. You need to delete in your .config folder the settings inside the xfwm4 folder...